# Animation not centered on imageView (iOS)

Tags: ios, animation

I have an image of a target, and I am trying to use animation to crop out the outer ring without resizing it.  I am using UIBelzierPath to do this, and I am some reason not able to center this directly on my image, as it animates only the bottom right corner, as supposed to the imageView directly.  What am I doing wrong?  I struggle with animation so any help would be wonderful.

```
@IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!

@IBAction func animate(sender: AnyObject) {
    animateCollapse()
}

private func animateCollapse() {
    let view = image
    let circleMaskPathInitial = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: view.frame)
    let circleMaskPathFinal = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(view.frame, 10 , 10))
    performAnimation(circleMaskPathInitial, finalPath: circleMaskPathFinal)
}

private func performAnimation(initialPath: UIBezierPath, finalPath: UIBezierPath) {

    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.path = finalPath.CGPath
    image.layer.mask = maskLayer

    let maskLayerAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    maskLayerAnimation.fromValue = initialPath.CGPath
    maskLayerAnimation.toValue = finalPath.CGPath
    maskLayerAnimation.duration = 1.0
    maskLayerAnimation.delegate = self
    maskLayer.addAnimation(maskLayerAnimation, forKey: "path")
}
```

image: [image]

image after animation: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `let circleMaskPathInitial = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: view.frame)` to `let circleMaskPathInitial = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: view.bounds)`. My guess is that you really want the rect's origin at (0, 0) of the image view, but its frame's origin is not (0, 0).

Comment: Also had to update circleMaskPathFinal with bounds -> UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectInset(view.bounds, 10 , 10))